# how would i call this function with a delegate as a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have repetitive code that i am trying to refactor into a generic function to generate a list of checkboxes from a list of objects (all lists of INamed).

The second parameter is a delegate that would call back into a function but i can't figure out how i would actually call this method.  What is the best way to call a method with this delegate? (I am looking for an example of code that would call Checkboxlist function)

```
public delegate bool HasHandler(INamed named);
```

here is the generic method

```
static public string CheckboxList(IQueryable<INamed> allItems, HasHandler has, string name)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in allItems)
        {
            if (has(item))
            {
                b.Append("<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' name='" + name + "' value=" + item.Id + " checked />" + item.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                b.Append("<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' name='" + name + "' value=" + item.Id + " />" + item.Name);
            }
        }
        return b.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, whenever you build HTML in a method like this, there is often a better way.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - do you have any specific suggestions for this example ?

Comment: Architecturally, you want to keep code that builds your View (a web page in this case?) in one place, and not let that leak into any of your inner logic.  JSP, Django, ASP.NET, etc. all have mechanisms for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it now:

```
if (has(item))  // This calls the delegate
```

That calls the delegate within the method.  The syntax you have is correct, and should work.

---

As for calling `CheckboxList` - it sounds like you need to have the delegate defined.  This can be any method which takes an "INamed" as a argument, and returns a boolean value.  For example, if you had:

```
private bool myHandler(INamed named)
{
    return true;
}
```

You could call this with:

```
string result = CheckboxList(items, myHandler, "Foo");
```

Alternatively, you could pass a lambda here:

```
string result = CheckboxList(items, named => { return (named.Foo > 3); }, "Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example:

```
public delegate bool HasHandler(INamed named);

// delete method matching HasHandler declaration
bool MyHandler(INamed named) {
    return true;
}

// method that passes your implemented delegate method as a parameter
void MyOtherMethod() {
    MyMethod(null, (n) => MyHandler(n)); // using lambda
    MyMethod(null, MyHandler); // not using lambda
}

// method that uses your implemented delegate method
// this would be like your CheckboxList method
void MyMethod(INamed o, HasHandler handler) {
    handler(o);
}
```

Notice the identifier `handler` is being used as a function with `o` (an object of `INamed`) as a parameter.

**EDIT**

An example of calling your `CheckboxList` method:

```
CheckboxList(myItems, (n) => MyHandler(n), "myName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBoxList(yourItems, x => x.SomeProperty == "foo", "yourName");
```